# How to change the color of text in an email template?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't have much knowledge of JS but I am just creating a simple template for email. In this template, I am trying to change the color of a text when the button is clicked. Although it is working fine on the localhost when I send an email, it does not work there and the console gives me no message.

**Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.** This message appears even before clicking on the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
<body>
    <center><h1>We're glad you're here, {{.GetAccountName}}</h1></center>
    <center onclick="func()" id="text">We just want to confirm it's you.<br><br></center>
    <center>
        <button onclick="func()">
            Click to confirm your email address
        </button>
    <center>
    <center><br>If you didn't create a proctl account, just delete this email.</center>

    <script>
        function func(){
            document.getElementById('text').style.color='blue';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The email client is likely sanitizing the content and preventing scripts from executing to prevent injection attacks.

You may confirm by inspecting the source for the message on delivery.

Comment: Then what to do?

Comment: If it is coming from the email client, there is nothing you can do about it since the capability is just not supported.

Comment: Is there any other way? If not then how a user can confirm an email address even if this small functionality is not working?